# how to clean a json string from double quotes and slashes in php

Tags: php, json

I have problem with json string in php.
 I have an app the get user contacts and send it to server and I process contacts in my way.

the problem is that some contacts name are very wired and some error occurred while using `json_decode()` 
contacts like this

```
[
   {"displayName":"Altin"'''''"''''"""""\n\""\p chapar","phoneNumbers":[{"value":"0411*******"}]},
   {"displayName":"A""""""basi","phoneNumbers":[{"value":"0914******"}]}
]
```

how can I clean this dirty json string to work properly?
I've tried to remove `"""` and `\\//` but I saw a huge amount of errors

thanks

Comment: Your JSON is broken, period. There's no obvious way how to fix it except manually if you know what it *should* look like. You need to ensure you're not producing invalid JSON in the first place (wherever this specific data is coming from…).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    $result = str_split($contacts);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
    {
        $found = false;

        if ($result[$i] == '"')
        {
            if ($result[$i + 1] != ':' && $result[$i + 1] != ',' 
                && $result[$i - 1] != '{' && $result[$i - 1] != '"' 
                    && $result[$i + 1] != '}' && $result[$i - 1] != ':' 
                        && $result[$i - 1] != ',')
                $result[$i] = '';
        }
    }

    $edited = implode("", $result);
    $edited = str_replace("'" , '' , $edited);
    $edited = str_replace("\\" , '' , $edited);
    $edited = str_replace("\n" , '' , $edited);
    print_r(json_decode($edited));
```

this will replace all inner double quotes so the string will be clean for the json_decode to produce std_objects.

Comment: How can you be sure that you can remove all quotes? JSON certainly allows quotes in string values, and you are just deleting them? JSON allows multiple backslashes, how else would one encode a backslash in a JSON string value? And you remove them.... This is a ***bad*** idea.

Comment: @MasoudTavakkoli, you'll get into trouble with this solution sooner or later. You'll think of me when you do. The ***only*** correct answer to your question is that you must fix the problem at the source: JSON must be valid. If it is not, there is no reliable way to fix it without making assumptions.

Comment: @trincot do you know a better way to do this? source is not in my side that's users contacts

Comment: Write to the owner of the source, explaining that the JSON they emit is invalid. They must fix it. I hope you realise that with this solution you might lose characters that were intended to be in the data.

Comment: dear @trincot, I think you didn't get my question properly. I can't change the source. I get this json from users phone contacts.

Comment: @trincot if you read his issue carefully he has a string inside json that includes double quotes so if you pass this string inside json_decode this will not parse correctly. so to fix this problem we are trying to remove those extra double quotes so json_decode will able to decode this.

Comment: @AmirHasanHesam, I have read the question carefully. All what I wrote above is valid. You cannot reliably decide how to fix a JSON that is broken. Some people have single quotes in their names, you know.

Comment: @MasoudTavakkoli, I did get your question properly. As I said, contact the producer of your data. If that is not possible (why should it not be?), then you'll need to find a different, more reliable data source. But I'll leave you to it. Good luck.